# Hibernate Spring : table not created [Unsuccessful: drop table if exists]

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am working on a angularjs spring mvc project and facing issues creating table using hibernate.

```
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.2.Final
Jun 18, 2016 4:54:49 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Hibernate: drop table if exists AppUser
Jun 18, 2016 4:54:49 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: drop table if exists AppUser
Jun 18, 2016 4:54:49 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Hibernate: create table AppUser (id integer not null auto_increment, dob varchar(255), email varchar(50), firstName varchar(255), lastName varchar(255), password varchar(255) not null, primary key (id))
Jun 18, 2016 4:54:49 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create table AppUser (id integer not null auto_increment, dob varchar(255), email varchar(50), firstName varchar(255), lastName varchar(255), password varchar(255) not null, primary key (id))
Jun 18, 2016 4:54:49 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

The model class is a simple class which looks like

```
@Entity
public class AppUser {


    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Email
    @Size(max = 50)
    private String email;

    @Column
    private String dob;

    @Column
    private String firstName;

    @Column
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    //getter setter

}
```

The data config file look like

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppDatabaseConfig {

    @Bean
    public HikariDataSource dataSource() {
       final HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource();
       ds.setMaximumPoolSize(100);
       ds.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); 
       ds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"); ;
       ds.setUsername("");
       ds.setPassword("");
       return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager manager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        manager.setSessionFactory(hibernate5SessionFactoryBean().getObject());
        return manager;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean hibernate5SessionFactoryBean(){
        LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        localSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        localSessionFactoryBean.setAnnotatedClasses(AppUser.class);

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        //properties.put("hibernate.current_session_context_class","thread");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto","create");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql","true");

        localSessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(properties);
        return localSessionFactoryBean;
    }

}
```

I tried chaning update / createdrop / create but gives error everytime. The DB does not contain the table. Not sure how to solve this ?

Comment: Use oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver instead of oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.
and hibernate.connection.driver_class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Comment: Which mysql database engine are you using. This might be due to a hibernate.dialect mismatch. The generated sql might not be compatible with your database engine

Comment: i am using oracle 11g

Comment: @azim still get the eror

Comment: The problem could be with the wrong JDBC Oracle driver. Please check whether you have any ojdbc6.jar.

Comment: If you want Hibernate to work with an Oracle database, you need to use the Oracle dialect, not the MySQL dialect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong dialect.

```
properties.put("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect")
```

For Oracle 11G you have to use

`org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect`

Please refer the official link to choose appropriate dialect

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html